# How to achieve drag and drop in taiko browser automation tool?

Tags: getgauge

Using taiko automation tool, we have completed a few level of automation testing for our application in browser.

To proceed further we need to achieve a drag and drop option, which is one of the necessary steps in our application.

Gone through taiko [feature's](https://taiko.gauge.org/#taiko-features) and found option like hover, scroll up, scroll down, etc.

How to achieve drag and drop using taiko?

Comment: Drag and drop was not supported in taiko, there is a feature request in Github.
https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/104

Comment: The feature is available from version 0.4.0

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dragAndDrop` api.

For e.g.

```
dragAndDrop($("work"),into($('work done')))
dragAndDrop($("work"),{up:10,down:10,left:10,right:10})
```

source https://taiko-preview.gauge.org/#draganddrop

Answer (score 0):

Drag and Drop is not supported in Taiko at the moment. The team has plans to pick this up - https://github.com/getgauge/taiko/issues/104